# Is there any difference parsing different IEnumerable in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I pass (just for display values) to the viewbag an array or a list.

Does it change something ( for the speed or memory ) when browsing the elements in a foreach with the razor engine?

Comment: What prompted this question? Your specific case would be useful information to add to this question.

Comment: Is there any difference compared to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance impact of choosing an array[] over an List is negligible in most cases.

Sure, array[] are less abstract and used "as is" in the CLR, but the hassle of loosing all the capabilities of List objects is usually not worth the minimal performance boost.

You can read more here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5777746/971693