# storing column value of each row in dataset into string[ ]

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, ado.net

i have a dataset with one table having 39 rows. now i wanna store the value of my id column value in a separate array like `string[]` ids.
i have define my array like this:

```
string[] ids = null;
```

and i m using this line to store values in this array:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < mydataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
ids[i] = mydataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
}
```

The Problem is that id column value is fetched but is not stored in ids array. it just throw an exception like Object reference not set an instance to an instance of object.
but when i use debug mode to inspect my code, my "id" column value is being fetched but is not stored in ids array.
can anyone help? what I m missing?
thanks...

Comment: you never initialize the array?

Answer (score 0):

You have declare array reference but not array actually being created you have to initialize it. You need to give size of array equal or greater to the expected elements.

```
string[] ids = new string[100];
```

You better use the List, its worth reading about the difference between two explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777729/what-is-difference-between-string-array-and-list-of-string-in-c-sharp).

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();

for ( int i = 0; i < mydataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ids.Add(mydataset.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you declared the array but not initialize it. you can do both declaration and initialize at ones as below;

```
string[] ids = mydataset.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r=>r["id"].ToString()).ToArray();
```