# Constructing a MasterMind game without using Arrays in c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a mastermind game without using arrays that generates 5 random numbers 1-9, and you have 15 tries to guess them.*=Correct -=WRONG +=incorrect positionbut the number is right.

I created the first part of it, and it works for trying to guess the first random digit of 1-9. I am unsure of how to goto the second number for the player to guess the second 1-9 digit, and how to make the code keep using the same int's/keep adding onto the guesses that I set up already. I tried everyway I knew how and I can't figure it out. If I could get some assistance of where I am going wrong, and how to set it up correctly it would be very much appreciated. Cheers

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Decisions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess the 5 Digit code, Under 15 tries!");

            Random myRandom = new Random();
            Int32 one = myRandom.Next(1, 10);
            Int32 two = myRandom.Next(1, 10);
            Int32 three = myRandom.Next(1, 10);
            Int32 four = myRandom.Next(1, 10);
            Int32 five = myRandom.Next(1, 10);
            int guesses = 0;
            bool incorrect = true;

            do
            {

                if (guesses < 15)
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 9");
                string result = Console.ReadLine();
                guesses++;

                if (guesses > 15)
                    Console.WriteLine("You went over 15 tries! Better luck next time");


                if (result == one.ToString())
                    incorrect = false;
                else if (result == two.ToString())
                    Console.WriteLine("+");
                else if (result == three.ToString())
                    Console.WriteLine("+");
                else if (result == four.ToString())
                    Console.WriteLine("+");
                else if (result == five.ToString())
                    Console.WriteLine("+");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("-");
            } while (incorrect);

            if (guesses < 15)
                Console.WriteLine("*Correct! It took {0} guesses.", guesses);
            if (guesses > 15)
                Console.WriteLine("You took to many tries! Better luck next time! Total Guesses: {0}", guesses);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to use array?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without arrays? Do you mow your lawn with nail clippers as well?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment where you are expected to use a List instead of an array?

Comment: @chadnt 

Yes, and My professor is practically useless with giving instructions, Just need some help in where I'm going wrong when trying to transition into guessing the next digit.

Comment: @Yukon, do they have to be guessed in order?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky Well at the end we would put the random int32's together, to form a 5 digit number.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky so the next number I been trying to make the game lead to, to guess would be Int32 two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking to use is a list.  But first -

Keep in mind you want to be careful about how you order things in your program, especially when it comes to user experience.  For instance:

```
if (guesses < 15)
    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 9");
string result = Console.ReadLine();
guesses++;

if (guesses > 15)
    Console.WriteLine("You went over 15 tries! Better luck next time");
```

So, when `guesses` is 14, it will show the text, have the user guess and increment "guesses" - however, when it iterates back to the beginning, your program will skip over the prompt: "Guess a number between 1 and 9" - but it will still wait for the users input.  After they put in their input it will prompt that they went over the amount of tries, but it will still check if that number matched!  **How you order your program can be very important to a users experience.**

Your program can look something like this:

```
    const int iMaxGuesses = 15;
    const int iListSize = 5;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random();

        // Hold a list of integers
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        int guesses = 0;

        // Value where we will rebuild the code
        string result = string.Empty;

        // Placeholder for user's guess
        string strGuess;

        // Converted guess
        int guess;

        // Generate random list of numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < iListSize; i++)
            numbers.Add(myRandom.Next(1, 10));

        // Prompt user
        Console.WriteLine("Guess the {0} Digit code, Under {1} tries!", iListSize, iMaxGuesses);

        // Open the game loop
        do
        {
            // Check if we have exceeded the max amount of times we get to guess
            if (guesses > iMaxGuesses)
                Console.WriteLine("You went over 15 tries! Better luck next time");
            else
            {
                // Prompt user
                Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 9");
                // Get input
                strGuess = Console.ReadLine();
                // Check if input is in fact an integer, if so - put the value in our variable 'guess'
                if (int.TryParse(strGuess, out guess))
                {
                    // We have a proper guess, increment
                    guesses++;
                    // Checks if the number is the next in our list
                    if (numbers[0] == guess)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, {0} was a match!", guess);
                        // Remove that from the List
                        numbers.Remove(numbers[0]);
                        // Add it to our sequence (result)
                        result += guess;
                    }
                    else if(numbers.Contains(guess))
                        Console.WriteLine("Right number, wrong spot!");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, please try again!");
                }
                else // Inform user we will only accept numbered input
                    Console.WriteLine("That was not a number.  Please try again!");
            }

        } while (guesses <= iMaxGuesses && numbers.Count > 0);

        if (guesses < iMaxGuesses)
            Console.WriteLine("Correct! It took {0} guesses to come up with the pattern {1}", guesses, result);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You took to many tries! Better luck next time! Total Guesses: {0}", guesses);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Couple things to note:  We have class-level constants for the List Size (we'll get to that) and how many guesses, in case these need to be changed on the fly.  You can ignore this.

The first thing you may notice is a List of integers `List<int> numbers = new List<int>()` Here is some [Reading (what is difference between string array and list of string in c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777729/what-is-difference-between-string-array-and-list-of-string-in-c-sharp) about the differences between Arrays and Lists (collections).

We initialize the list of Random numbers by creating a loop the max size of our list, and ADDING a random integer to that list.

On the Do/While loop, we are checking that we are still less than iMaxGuesses **and** we have objects left in our list.  So we take the users input.  First we use `int.TryParse`to determine if we do actually have a number.  If we **do have a number**, we will check that against the first number that appears in the list, `numbers[0]`, and if it does, we remove it from the list: `numbers.Remove(numbers[0]);` The cool part about lists, is that when you REMOVE an item, it resizes the list, unlike an array that has a fixed size.  So if your list is **12345**, and you remove the 1, the next time you check the value of `numbers[0]`, it will be 2!

I'm pretty sure the rest should be self explanatory.  Let me know if anything was missed or you need help understanding anything.

Comment: I figured out 
"                        if (numbers[0] != guess)
                                        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, Try Again!");"
And it works, Now I just need one that tells you if it's correct, but just in the wrong number position. So how would I manage to be able to check if your answer input is equal to number[0], but not including the number you are currently trying to guess for, or the previous numbers you have already guessed?

Comment: Well, if the "if (numbers [0] == guess)", returns false, you can use "else if (numbers.Contains (guess))" to see if that number appears anywhere else in the list.  Wrap that if statement up with an else to display the "Incorrect, Try again" message instead of checking that numbers [0] != guess.

Comment: Where exactly would I put 
else if (numbers.Contains (guess))
WriteLine("Incorrect, but correct position");

and 

else
WriteLine("Incorrect, Try again");

I tried putting my   "else if"   statement above my  "else"  statement that tells the user that what they entered is not a correct value, but it returned the "Incorrect, but correct position" every single time no matter what.

Comment: I'll update my answer later.  On the road.  Stand by

Comment: Answer is updated, but understand: your question as to where the else if/else should go is quite simple: follow the logic.  Remember, you want to check if that number exists in the list AFTER you check if it's the next number (and that fails) - that's why it's an "else if."

Hope that makes sense, and happy programming.

Comment: Thanks, Just to ask for future reference would it matter if the "else if", came after the "else"? I'm trying to figure out where I placed it wrong, that made it show up no matter if it was wrong or right.

Comment: YES it matters.  "else" alone means: "if all else fails"  and it HAS to be at the end of the if/then/else block.  If->else if->else.